# Application Loader Errors (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, app-store, appstore-approval, submission

I am getting these error messages when trying to send my application's binary to Apple.

```
Info.plist does not contain a CFBundleResourceSpecification
Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate.
```

Not sure what's wrong. Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: Anything here help? http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2009/qa1524.html

Comment: Hmm now I am getting the "Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate." warning in Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try downloading the distribution certificate from the apple provisioning site. Go through all the steps again.
If that doesn't work. Delete all of the provisioning files from your iphone/ipod and your mac's keychain

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are uploading your iPhone Distribution build?  Codesigned by your Distribution profile?  And not some Debug or Simulator build?  And not something signed by your Developer certificate?